# What did the word 'unconstitutional' mean to Americans prior to the Revolution?

Tags: law, american-revolution, constitution, colonial-america

I'm reading about the Townshend Acts on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Townshend_Acts#Raising_revenue), and it says that the American colonists rejected any taxation because it was unconstitutional. Were they referring to a specific document, like the Magna Carta?

Comment: The literal question in your title does not reflect the question in the body. Could you please edit to ask one or the other?

Comment: Also, I haven't read that wiki page, but the colonists would not have considered the act unconstitutional prior to there being a constitution, right? The would have considered the taxation by the Crown perhaps to be unlawful, or unjust, or unequal to those same taxes being levied on other parts of the empire.

Comment: This can be trivially answered by [reading the cited work](http://books.google.com/books?id=rKuMmntKzNgC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) from the Wikipedia page. Starts on page 10.

Comment: @CGCampbell I think they would have been reasonable well aware of the British constitution.

Comment: Rather a fascinating question in that it reveals some interesting varieties of constitution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They were referring to the **unwritten constitution** of the British Empire. Magna Carta was only a part of that. Without commenting on its legality, validity or morality, the argument was that Parliament could not extract money from the colonies without their consent. The constitutional principle involved being, of course, that of **taxation without representation**.

> [The colonies] are the subjects of this kingdom, equally entitled with yourselves to all the natural rights of mankind and the peculiar privileges of Englishmen; equally bound by its laws, and **equally participating in the constitution of this free country.** The Americans are the sons, not the bastards, of England! Taxation is no part of the governing or legislative power. **The taxes are a voluntary gift and grant of the Commons alone.**
>
> (...)
>
> When, therefore, in this House we give and grant, we give and grant what is our own. But in an American tax, what do we do? “We, your majesty’s Commons for Great Britain, give and grant to your majesty”—what? Our own property! No! “We give and grant to your majesty” **the property of your majesty’s *Commons of America*!** It is an absurdity in terms.
>
> **<sub>- William Pitt, The Earl of Chatham,</sub>**

It was generally agreed that that power was vested in Parliament to preside over all the disparate parts of the British Empire. Some colonists argued that this only meant Parliament had the right to **regulate trade and commerce**, in order to promote the common welfare of both Great Britain *and* her colonies. It was conceded that Parliament could impose duties for this purpose, just as fines could be imposed in order to uphold the king's peace.

> I have looked over every statute relating to these colonies, from their first settlement to this time; and I find every one of them founded on this principle till the Stamp Act administration. **All before are calculated to regulate trade and preserve or promote a mutually beneficial intercourse** between the several constituent parts of the Empire; and though many of them imposed duties on trade, yet those duties were always imposed with design to restrain the commerce of one part, that was injurious to another, and thus to promote the general welfare ...  Never did the British Parliament, till the period above mentioned, think of imposing duties in America **for the purpose of raising a revenue.**
>
> <sub>**- John Dickinson's [*Letter II from a Farmer in Pennsylvania*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letters_from_a_Farmer_in_Pennsylvania)**</sub>

The charges of unconstitutionality was generated when Parliament began passing laws with an *explicitly expressed intent to "raise revenue"*. This was interpreted as taxation without the justification of regulating the colonial trade, and consequently denounced by some (on both sides of the Atlantic) as unconstitutional. They believed, as William Pitts argued, that the gift and grant of *colonial* tax belonged to the *colonial* legislatures, rather than Westminister.

Comment: The Empire had incurred a huge amount of debt defending the American colonies in the Seven Years War though, right? And they kept a large standing army there afterwards to deter any more aggression from France and to protect the frontier in general? So the need to raise revenue should have been obvious to the Americans. And the British Empire even tried to make it cheap enough for the Americans to pay for eventually, repealing the Stamp Acts, most of the Townshend Acts, and making tea from the British East India Tea Company cheap enough to undercut Dutch tea even after taxes.

Comment: It almost seems like the "unconstitutionality" of the taxes was a small issue that was blown out of proportion by vested interests, with the aim of stirring up rebellion.

Comment: All of the things you suggest @Broseph are true from modern eyes; remember that macroeconomics simply didn't exist at the time, and contemporary economic theory was ill prepared to confront the questions.

Comment: The second comment however is less useful; judgement of the past interferes with understanding the past.

Comment: @Broseph As a side note, making the East India Company tea cheaper to re-export to America was a *bailout* to keep the Company afloat - it had a massive, rotting stockpile of tea at the time. Quite a costly bailout as it turns out.

Comment: @Semaphore Yeah, I was aware of that. Corporate bailouts and lobbying have been around for way longer than the US it seems :p .

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I am an anarchist, and I am very sceptical of the validity of modern economics. I just thought that if the colonists believed a government can have any "right" to tax, that they shouldn't be so bothered by this. Also, I am not so sure that people at the time were ignorant of macroeconomics, since it seems Parlaiment had access to a lot of data and statistics about the economy, and made their decisions based on predicted changes to the economy. They seemed pretty well aware of the economics behind their ideas, just not the political climate of the colonies.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Also, I still don't buy that the taxes seemed unconstitutional to people before they were stirred up. People like to mention that there was argument against the taxation on "both sides of the Atlantic," but the majority was obviously convinced this was ok. If they could do it to control trade, why is doing it to gain revenue, and provide colonist with cheaper goods, a bad thing? The fact that a pure cost/benefit analysis of the situation would have led people to just pay the taxes is what makes me suspicious.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace and I am not just pulling this judgement out of thin air. I read an article in the William and Mary Quarterly about the passage of the Sugar Act, and it seems that the colonies were not very interested in it at the time of it's passage, even though they had sent agents to London to communicate with the colonial governments about it.

Comment: @Broseph IMHO, agreeing that duties could be imposed for "regulating trade" was probably more of an example of [*concession-refutation*](http://www.lirvin.net/WGuides/argue.htm). Also, the Sugar Act did cause discontentment when economic effects was felt; it was followed so closely by the Stamp Act that it seems reasonable to say general opposition to Parliament simply tuned in on the latter.

Comment: Macroeconomics was invented by Keynes in the 20th century; Parliament in the 18th century didn't have access to macroeconomic theory.  Mike Duncan's [podcast](http://www.revolutionspodcast.com/2014/02/017-the-new-world.html) does a pretty good job of covering the hypocrisy of the Colonists on taxation. I think I've dragged out a conversation in comments beyond what is wise; if you're interested in the topic, let's move this to a new question.

Comment: of course the Magna Charta has no constitutional status anywhere near what an American would understand today a constitution to mean. It's more of a guideline than a law, and should be understood as such.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer:** No, the colonists were not referring to a specific document. The colonists were referring to the fact that they believed it was beyond the powers of Parliament to tax them because the colonists did not have representation in Parliament.

**Long Answer:** The American colonists were not referring to a specific document like the Magna Carta, or any other document for that matter. It is important to remember that at this time the colonists still thought of themselves as part of the British empire. As such, the colonists were referring to the British concept of a constitution, unwritten as pointed out by Semaphore, where the Parliament had specific powers, and the people had certain rights. There are, however, [historical documents like the Magna Carta that make up the British constitution](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/constitution-unit/whatis/uk-constitution).

The colonists would have been quite familiar with the British "constitution." As Bernard Bailyn put it, what was within the constitution was an "arrangement of governmental institutions, laws, and customs together with the principles and goals that animated them." (66-71). Bailyn quotes John Adams, who wrote a constitution of government is "a frame, a scheme, a system, a combination of powers for a certain end, namely, the good of the whole community." (68). Pauline Meir states in *American Scripture: Making the Declaration of Independence* that "Americans took particular pride in being governed under Britain's unwritten constitution, which they considered the most perfect form of government ever invented." (29).

The issue in the case of the Stamp Act and the Townshend Acts, was one of taxation without representation. The colonies did not have representatives in the Parliament. Up to the time of the Stamp Act the American colonies had been largely left alone by Parliament, meaning they had not been subject to internal taxes and left to govern their affairs largely on their own. This period was known as [salutary neglect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salutary_neglect).

When the Stamp Act was passed it was the first major internal tax on the colonies, and as Walter Issacson points out Benjamin Franklin believed it "unwise, perhaps even unconstitutional, for Parliament to levy an internal tax on people who had no representation in that assembly." (222). Whether or not this was a correct interpretation is besides the point. The point is that the consensus in the colonies eventually became that the Parliament lacked the power to levy such taxes, because of the representation issue. As a commenter on the question noted in referring to a  *Constitutional History of the American Revolution: The Authority to Tax*, the colonists believed that such powers could only be executed by their local officials, *not* by Parliament itself. (Reid 9-11).

In a way, the colonists concept of what was or wasn't constitutional is not that different from our present day idea of what is or isn't constitutional. Namely, is what the government doing within the powers possessed by the government, ie constitutional?

**References**

- [Bailyn, Bernard. *The Ideological Origins of the American Revolution*.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674443020)
- [Isaacson, Walter. *Benjamin Franklin: An American Life.*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/074325807X)
- [Reid, Ralph. *Constitutional History of the American Revolution: The Authority to Tax*.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/029911290X)
- [Maier, Pauline. *American Scripture: Making the Declaration of Independence.*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0679779086)